# Iteration of inner loop for specified times

Tags: jsp, struts2, iteration

I want to iterate comboBoxList which contains 60 items, I want to iterate 10 10 entries for each iteration.

I am having two `<s:property />` values that contains integer values in jsp. I want to add them for iteration.

```
<s:set var="start" value="1"/> 
<s:set var="end" value="#session['tlists'].size()"/>
<s:iterator var="param"  value="#session['params']"> <%-- #session['params'] contains 10 entries--%>
    <s:property/> <%-- comboBoxList is 6*10 --%>

    <s:iterator var="comboBox"  begin="start" end="end" value="#session['comboBoxList']">
        <s:property />
    </s:iterator>

    <s:set var="start">
        <s:param name="value">
            <s:property value="end"/>+1  <%--Showing error--%>
        </s:param>
    </s:set>

    <s:set var="end">
        <s:param name="value">
            <%-- tlists.size() is 6 --%>
            <s:property value="end"/>+<s:property value="#session['tlists'].size()"/> <%-- Showing error --%>
        </s:param>
    </s:set>
```

Trying to get output like:

```
param1  cb11    cb12 cb13 cb14  cb15   cb16
param2  cb21    cb22 cb23 cb24  cb23   cb24
param3  cb31    cb32 cb33 cb34  cb33   cb34
param4  cb41    cb42 cb43 cb44  cb43   cb44
.
.
.
.
.
.
```

Comment: you can use iterator `end` attribute

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi I am trying but    <s:property value="end"/>+1                    <s:property value="end"/>+<s:property value="#session['tlists'].size()"/>   showing error

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi does iterator have an `end` attribute, can you show me the `apidoc`, i just found `last`

Comment: @Jaiwo99:The `begin`, `end` and `step` attributes are only available from 2.1.7 on, here is the link for you http://struts.apache.org/2.3.4/docs/iterator.html

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi Nice, thanks, my apidoc link is too old.. hahaha...

Comment: @Jaiwo99 start and end are variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried this this is working properly what I want
Is there any other way for doing

```
 <s:property value="end"/>+1
```

Code for above problem is

```
<s:iterator var="fparam"  value="#session['feedbackparam']">
    <tr align="center">
        <td align="right">
            <s:property value="param"/>
        </td> 
<s:iterator var="comboBox"  status="count" begin="start" end="end" value="#session['comboBoxList']">
        <td align="centre">
            <s:property escapeHtml="false"/>
        </td>
 </s:iterator>
</tr>
    <s:set var="start" value="%{#end+1}"/>
    <s:set var="end"  value="%{#end+#session['tlists'].size()}"/>

</s:iterator>
```